# ValueError: Layer weight shape (32, 128) not compatible with provided weight shape (32, 64)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I'm training an autoencoder and after tuning the autoencoder, I'm taking the encoder part, add a fully connected layer for a regression problem. After training the autoencoder, when I'm trying to combine the encoder and fully connected layer, it shows the following error

`ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 128 and 64. Shapes are [32,128] and [32,64]. for 'Assign_36' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [32,128], [32,64].`

I understand somewhere I have a mismatched dimension but I can't identify. Sorry, I'm new to this. Here are the relevant codes.

```
def encoder(input_data):
    encoder1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(input_data)
    encoder1 = BatchNormalization()(encoder1)
    encoder1 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(encoder1)
    encoder1 = BatchNormalization()(encoder1)

    encoder2 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(encoder1)
    encoder2 = BatchNormalization()(encoder2)
    encoder2 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(encoder2)
    encoder2 = BatchNormalization()(encoder2)

    encoder3 = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(encoder2)
    encoder3 = BatchNormalization()(encoder3)
    encoder3 = Dense(32, activation = 'relu')(encoder3)
    encoder3 = BatchNormalization()(encoder3)

    return encoder3

def decoder(encoder, input_data):
    decoder3 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(encoder)
    decoder3 = BatchNormalization()(decoder3)
    decoder3 = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(decoder3)
    decoder3 = BatchNormalization()(decoder3)

    decoder2 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(decoder3)
    decoder2 = BatchNormalization()(decoder2)
    decoder2 = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(decoder2)
    decoder2 = BatchNormalization()(decoder2)

    decoder1 = Dense(788, activation = 'sigmoid')(decoder2)

    return decoder1

def fc(enco):
    den = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(enco)
    out = Dense(1, activation = 'tanh')(den)

    return out

input_data = Input(shape=(788, ))
autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoder(encoder(input_data), input_data))
autoencoder.compile(optimizer = 'adadelta', loss ='mse')
autoencoder.fit(train_x, train_x,
                epochs = 5,
                batch_size = 32,
                shuffle = True,
                validation_data = (test_x, test_x))

# building combined model
encode = encoder(input_data)
full_model = Model(input_data, fc(encode))
full_model.set_weights(autoencoder.get_weights())    # ValueError
```

Comment: which line is the error happening on? Also, can you have a minimal complete verifiable example? Something that can be copy-pasted where we can immediately see the error?

Comment: The error is in this line ``full_model.set_weights(autoencoder.get_weights())``

Comment: If I had to guess, it's likely because you're taking the weights for the autoencoder (encoder and decoder) and trying to set an encoder with the weights with all of it (enc and dec). Try printing `autoencoder.get_weights()` and `full_model.get_weights()` before running the `set_weights`

Comment: Got it working. It's in the `fc()` where I set the Dense layer size 128 which should be 64 since that's how it is designed in the autoencoder. See in the `encoder()` the layer 32 makes a weight matrix of `32 x 64`. So when I cut the encoder and joined it with a fully connected layer, the first layer in the fully connected layer is 128 which is a mismatch from `32 x 64`. So instead of 128 in `den = Dense(128, activation = 'relu')(enco)` it should be `den = Dense(64, activation = 'relu')(enco)`. Hope this helps some in future.